# C++ Anyone know more about this kind of pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a World class and a Entity class.
The World class creates new Entites and retuns a pointer to it.
If i use that pointer im never sure if that pointer is still pointing to a valid Entity but i also dont want to use a shared_ptr because the Entity wont get deleted until all shared_ptr are released. So after some time i cameup with this pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

template<class T>
class Pointer
{
public:

    Pointer() :m_ptr(nullptr){}
    Pointer(T*p) :m_ptr(p) { m_ptr->addPtr(this); }

    ~Pointer() { if(valid()) m_ptr->removePtr(this); }

    Pointer(const Pointer &other) :m_ptr(other.m_ptr) 
    {
        if(valid())
            m_ptr->addPtr(this);
    }

    Pointer& operator=(const Pointer& other)
    {
        if (valid())
            m_ptr->removePtr(this);

        m_ptr = other.m_pObj;

        if (valid())
            m_ptr->addPtr(this);

        return *this;
    }

    T* operator->() { return m_ptr; }
    T* operator*() { return *m_ptr; }

    T* get() { return m_ptr; }
    bool valid() { return m_ptr != nullptr; }

private:

    template<typename T>
    friend class PointerCollector;

    T * m_ptr;

};

template <class T>
class PointerCollector
{
public:

    PointerCollector() = default;
    virtual ~PointerCollector()
    {
        for (auto &x : m_ptrList)
        {
            (x.second)->m_ptr = nullptr;
        }
    }

private:

    void addPtr(Pointer<T> *ptr)
    {
        m_ptrList[ptr] = ptr;
    }
    void removePtr(Pointer<T> *ptr)
    {
        m_ptrList.erase(ptr);
    }

    template<typename T>
    friend class Pointer;

    std::unordered_map<Pointer<T>*, Pointer<T>*> m_ptrList;
};


class Test : public PointerCollector<Test>
{
public:
    Test() {}
    ~Test() = default;

    int getVal() { return m_val; }

private:

    int m_val = 100;
};



void func(Pointer<Test> ptr)
{
    if (ptr.valid())
    {
        std::cout << ptr->getVal();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid!\n";
    }

}

int main()
{
    Test* myTest = new Test();

    Pointer<Test> myPtr(myTest);
    Pointer<Test> myPtr2(myPtr);

    delete myTest;

    func(myPtr2);


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

the Test class will collect the pointers to it and invalidates them if the class gets deleted.

Now i wanted to ask if anyone knows a better implementation or more infomation about this kind of pointer.

I compiled and tested the above code in Visual Studio 2017

Comment: The use case you describe in your opening paragraph would be satisfied by returning a `shared_ptr`, with the World holding a `weak_ptr`

Comment: Where are `World` and `Entity` in the code you posted?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile. It'd help to post code you actually compiled and tested; and also provide a description of what the code is supposed to do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak-ptr

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com would be a better place for this question

Comment: `Pointer` needs a destructor that removes itself from `PointerCollector`. As written, `PointerCollector` may end up holding dangling references, and attempting to clear them. Also, you can use `unordered_set` in place of `unordered_map` - at the moment, the value is always the same as the key, and is redundant.

Comment: As to what kind - as already noted, `Pointer` is essentially a reinvention of `std::weak_ptr`, except that it uses an intrusive control block (which is what `PointerCollector` is).

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik im sorry i dont know how i missed the destructor i fixed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, this pattern has been used before by many people. You just created a poor (and broken, because there's at least one outright bug and several things that are sub-optimal) re-implementation of [`::std::weak_ptr<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr). You should consider using it instead.